# Adobe XD Export not converting on HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, adobe, prototype, adobe-xd

I created a background shape in Adobe XD and I initially export it as SVG, but when I reference it my HTML CSS code the shape is not as I created it.

I export as PNG and is the same problem.

when I access the export file the png format is displaying properly until I had it to display on the web.

css:

```
   background: #1F4C73;
   background-image: url('../img/web/hero-bg.png') no-repeat ;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

HTML:

```
<section class="top"></div>
```

Comment: Have manage to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Have manage to fix it. For some reason it was the same technique have used before, but it works now.